# A homotopy equivalence between two sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I was trying to prove that the set consisting of the union of the circles $\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid(x-10)^2 +y^2 = 1\}$, $\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid(x+10)^2 +y^2 = 1\}$ and line segment $\{\langle x, 0\rangle\mid x\in[-9,9]\}$, is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of two circles.To do so I tried to start from the wedge sum of two bigger circles and deformation retract them to the set given , but I couldn't do it , and also I tried to collapse the line to a point then move one of the circles to meet the other , but this doesn't seem to be right, can anyone help me please?

Comment: The quotient map $X\to X/A$, where $A$ is the line segment and $X$ is its union with the two circles, is a homotopy equivalence. This follows from the fact that $A$ is contractible together with the fact that the pair $(X,A)$  is *cofibered*. A proof can be found in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, chapter 0.

Comment: i just read it,and i have a problem understanding it actually , what i understood is that both spaces are deformation retract of the same space which is a disk with two smaller open sub-disks removed,but i don't understand the deformation retraction mentioned about the cylinder Mf and the quotient space , can you please explain it to me . @StefanHamcke

Comment: Did you read proposition 0.17?

Comment: no not really i read the first two pages where he mentioned what i wrote in the comment , i will read it and come back if i had any question Thank you for your help .

Comment: That proposition is the essential ingredient here. Of course, one has to show that $(X,A)$ is cofibered, and that $X/A$ is homeomorphic to the wedge of circles, but that shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: I can show also that this space is a deformation retract of R^2 -{p,q} , and so is the wedge sum of 2 circles , and they will be homeomorphic right? I  didn't do it yet but this is my intuition , and thank you for your generous help .